# Net Core Identity - use current login in SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have .NET Core 2.1 web application which Identity authentication on and SQL Server 2017 database.

Every table in my database will contain a column (say: change_user) holding info about the user which inserted or last updated the record.

Suppose that user `jsmith` logins into the web app and clicks the button that deploys  the stored proc which inserts a record into sometable table. So, the stored proc needs to set sometable.change_user columnn for that record.

Of course I could pass a param to the stored proc from C# level. I would prefer to handle that completely on server side and take the desired info from some session variable etc. Is such approach possible?

Comment: On server side, how do you know that which user is logged in without sending it from the code side...? Just like `jsmith` there are n number of users logged in, you cannot differentiate from server side only that which user is logged in or send request.

Comment: I am trying to ask if .NET Core Identity implements such mechanism that would save me sending login info again and again from my code. Answer "this is impossible" also puts me forward. Thanks.

Comment: I was exactly looking for same approach. The table that insert the record has triggers and it will update the user inserted/update columns. Did you find any solution? Thanks

Comment: @pavany As far as I can remember - I gave up after reading answers to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send the logged in user information to a stored proc without writing code, but you can make that code pretty simple.

Assume you have some service that is called by your controller.  You define it as

`Servicec(MyDbContext context, IHttpContextAccessor accessor)`

Your dbcontext and the IHttpContext accessor are both registered in Startup as scoped services.

This in your service you can do

```
var userName = accessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
```

I think this is the easiest way to describe the process, but you can elaborate on it quite a bit. For example, you can inject the username into the DbContext and have it always add the username to entities that are being changed in an overloaded version of DbContext.SaveChangesAsync before you call base.ChangesAsync.